# Installing multiple packages with one yum command

Tags: fedora, yum

Is there a way to install 2 or more packages using one yum command

```
yum install mysql php vsftp
```

Comment: I just tried your command, and it works ok. Why didn't you try it out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use the exact command from your question. `yum` can take multiple package names as input:

```
yum install mysql php vsftp
```

Comment: would this work? `yum install -y php mysql`

Comment: Yes it works like a charm on my laptop running Fedora 14.

Comment: It helps if you summarize the link, so the user doesn't have to click through and they're not screwed if the link breaks

Comment: It just says "Yum accepts multiple arguments, so just specify all of them on the command line" in various ways. I don't think that having a link to some random forum posts that say that actually is useful.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I do it all the time. Any yum command will work with multiple packages specified, just take a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum).